# Manually reordering windows taskbar items in same application in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

Is there any way to manually reorder windows taskbar items in same application in **Windows 10**

For example, if someone has opened instances of the same application in taskbar buttons are displaying in groups if you hover or click on the application group button on taskbar small window displayed for each window in the order of opening of the application windows. Is there any sophisticated way to reorder them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YEs there is.  It's pretty (or) somewhat popular: It's called "Windows 7 Taskbar" tweaks? If I recall.

Found it here it is:
https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

You need to run it constant or tweaks will reverse. 
So if not looking reversal - auto-starting it with the OS might be solution your after.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I also tried Groupy same... and it is bugged beyond belief! https://www.stardock.com/products/groupy/ Also I need to rename windows on taskbar!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, and I can just close it after reordering.