# Automatic ordering taskbar previews in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, when you hover over a running application icon in a taskbar, a preview of its all opened windows is generated. The order of them usually depends on the order of running them, and that's often confusing when I work for a long time with many windows on split-screen and I swap them.

Is there any build-in (or not) option to **automatically** (I know I can do it manually with [*7+ Taskbar Tweaker*](https://superuser.com/a/1335668/1262395) but during this time I'll find my window, make and drink a coffee) order the previews by the <s>appearance</s> arrangement on the screen (from left to right*)?

[image: example]

---

* I think, the way to order them by the sequence of usage would be very interesting too. However, I'm looking for the first method especially.

Comment: I do not know of any automatic method. I know I stack icons and can easily pick out the main icon, hover and find what I want in seconds. I have more issue with At-Tab as I like to sequence this to my current two apps.